# How to read multiple JSON files from GCS bucket in google dataflow apache beam python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm having a bucket in GCS that contain list of JSON files. I came to extract the list of the file names using

```
def list_blobs(bucket_name):


    storage_client = storage.Client()

    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    json_paths = []
    for blob in blobs:
        json_paths.append(f"gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name}")
    return json_paths
```

Now I want to pass this list of filenames to apache beam to read them. I wrote this code, but it doesn't seem a good pattern

```
for i,file in enumerate(list_files):
        print("parsing file:", file)
        concat_data = (p |'Data {}'.format(i) >> ReadFromText(file)
        )
        final_result.append(concat_data)
```

Have you faced the same issue before?

Comment: Have you checked the ReadAll transforms?

Comment: @Iñigo can you read my reply for the answer that Mr.Batra answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I came to use the google-cloud storage as reading API for this.

Listing all elements of the bucket

```
def list_blobs(bucket_name):
"""Lists all the blobs in the bucket."""

storage_client = storage.Client()
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
json_paths = []
for blob in blobs:
    #json_paths.append(f"gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name}")
    json_paths.append(f"{blob.name}")
return json_paths
```

and I created this ParDo for reading the content

```
class ReadFileContent(beam.DoFn):

def setup(self):
    # Called whenever the DoFn instance is deserialized on the worker.
    # This means it can be called more than once per worker because multiple instances of a given DoFn subclass may be created (e.g., due to parallelization, or due to garbage collection after a period of disuse).
    # This is a good place to connect to database instances, open network connections or other resources.
    self.storage_client = storage.Client()

def process(self, file_name, bucket_name):
    bucket = self.storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.get_blob(file_name)
    yield blob.download_as_string()
```

And mu pipeline looked like this:

```
list_files = list_blobs(bucket_name)

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    results = (
        p | 'Create' >> beam.Create(list_files)
          | 'Read each file content' >> beam.ParDo(ReadFileContent(), bucket_name)
          | 'next transformation' >> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadAllFromText) link. The ReadFromText is a PTransform that helps reading a text file. On the other hand *ReadAllFromText* is a PTransform that reads *PCollection* of text files. Reads a PCollection of text files or file patterns and produces a PCollection of strings.

Comment: The issue that I've found with the ReadAllFromText  is it reads my entire JSON files into one string text that when it is passed to the next transformation it reads each line separatly .. and my need is to have the entire json string for each line to be processed separately.

Comment: In that case I would recommend not to use ReadFromText. Instead use Json module from python. The code would look like this

beam.Create([list of file])
beam.Map(transform_json)
......

In the transform_json function you can use the fn from that module. For Eg
def transform_json(file_path):
      with open(file_path) as f:
           json.load(f)

here is the link https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: That's what I'm thinking about, I created a function for reading the content of the JSON file stored in a GCS bucket using google-storage API and then reading the content using JSON module and pass it to the next transformation. My concerns if this is a bad pattern for processing hundreds of thousands of JSON files with each time you create an Instance of the storage API and you call GCS for getting the content of the file

Comment: I found the DoFn.setup() method that, according to the documentation, is good place to connect to database instances, open network connections or other resources.  https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.32.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.setup

Answer (score 0):

This is another answer that is more optimised if you have few JSONs to process. You can use `ReadFromText` transformation with a path pattern:

```
(p | 'Read content' >> ReadFromText('gs://bucket/folder/*')
   | 'String to JSON' >> beam.Map(lambda k: json.loads(k))
```